# Larger than expected file sizes when saving a TIFF with OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, tiff

I am creating a python program to load a .tiff image, crop out a selection from the image, and save the selection as a tiff. The dataset images are large, exceeding 1GB. I can successfully crop out what I need and save as a tiff, but the new image file sizes are much larger than what I expect and need.

**Opening**
I am using tifffile to open the image as a numpy array. OpenCV and PIL were not able to open the files due to size. I tried using OpenSlide as well, but encountered other problems down the road with `read_region()`.

**Cropping**
The numpy array has the shape `(height, width, 3)`, so I crop using something like `large_image[top:bottom, left:right, :]`. This works as intended.

**Saving**
Using `cv2.imwrite()` has resulted in the smallest file sizes thus far, but they are still much larger than they should be. `PIL.Image.save()` and `TiffWriter` from `tifffile` created even larger images.

Best results: Cropping 13 new images from a 250MB file - using only about 20% of the original image - gives me files totaling over 900MB. I would expect the total to be something like 50MB.

*Note*:  The cropped .tiff files have correct dimensions. If the original is `200,000 x 50,000`, then the cropped file will be, say,  `8,000 x 3,000`. Also, I am unable to open the original 250MB image using Preview on my Mac, but I can quickly open a 500MB cropped image created by my program when I save the image with `TiffWriter` (I can open files saved with opencv as well).

Summary of the code:

```
import tifffile
import cv2
import numpy as np

original_image = tifffile.imread('filepath') #original_image is a numpy array

#...calculations for top, bottom, etc...

cropped_image = original_image[top:bottom, left:right, :]
cv2.imwrite('output_filepath', cropped_image)
```

These 3 lines are all the IO that I use.

tl;dr - trying to load images, crop, and save new images as .tiff, but new file sizes are much larger than expected.

Comment: There is no single “TIFF format”. TIFF can contain images in many, many different ways. In particular, data can be compressed with different methods. It is likely that your input image is compressed with JPEG or JPEG2000, whereas the TIFFs you’re writing are not compressed or compressed with a lossless format.

Comment: Why I cant see a question mark in the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac, **homebrew** is great and you can install `libtiff` and **ImageMagick** with:

```
brew install libtiff imagemagick
```

Then you can really start to understand what compression, number of bits/sample and data sizes/types using:

```
tiffinfo YOURINPUTFILE.TIF
tiffinfo YOUROUTPUTFILE.TIF
```

and:

```
magick identify -verbose YOURINPUTFILE.TIF
magick identify -verbose YOUROUTPUTFILE.TIF
```

If you want to see the two side-by-side, use:

```
magick identify -verbose YOURINPUTFILE.TIF  > a
magick identify -verbose YOUROUTPUTFILE.TIF > b
opendiff a b
```