# TIFF Images representation as numpy array

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff, numpy-ndarray

I tried converting tiff images into numpy arrays. I used PIL to open it and then passed it to *np.array()*

```
img1 = Image.open(img1_path)
temp = np.array(img1)
print('TYPE:' + str(type(temp)))
print(temp)
```

Here's the output:

```
TYPE:<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[1342 1435 1428 ... 1165 1168 1170]
 [1407 1376 1267 ... 1175 1148 1166]
 [1336 1454 1434 ... 1174 1159 1169]
 ...
 [1204 1201 1302 ... 1115 1131 1126]
 [1202 1246 1305 ... 1125 1129 1118]
 [1285 1319 1319 ... 1127 1124 1127]]
```

The shape of array is - (858, 557)

When we convert any image into numpy array, we usually see values ranging from 1-255, but how are we seeing values so much higher than that? I don't know a lot about tiff files. And I can't understand this concept. Any help or resources would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could be a 16-bit image.

Comment: I had dataset consisting of pairs 13-band multispectral satellite images obtained by the Sentinel-2 satellites, and this is the tiff file of a single band.

Comment: Have a look here to work out what you've got... https://stackoverflow.com/a/62860068/2836621