# Converting TIFF file to JPEG when using Imagecodecs Python library gives an error

Tags: python-3.x, image

I am using the Imagecodecs Python library to convert TIFF files to JPEG files and one of my images are causing an error in the program.  When it gets to the file I get the following error.  Anyone know why I would be getting this?

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
TIFF_DECODE: Sorry, can not handle image
PNG_DECODE: not a PNG image
GIF_DECODE: DGifCloseFile returned 'Data is not in GIF format'
WEBP_DECODE: WebPGetFeatures returned VP8_STATUS_BITSTREAM_ERROR
JPEG8_DECODE: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x49 0x49
JPEG12_DECODE: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x49 0x49
JPEGSOF3_DECODE: decode_jpegsof3 returned 'JPEG signature 0xFFD8FF not found'
JPEG2K_DECODE: not a J2K or JP2 data stream
JPEGLS_DECODE: charls_jpegls_decoder_read_header returned Invalid JPEG-LS stream, the leading start byte (0xFF) for a JPEG marker was not found
JPEGXR_DECODE: PKCodecFactory_CreateDecoderFromBytes returned WMP_errUnsupportedFormat
JPEGXL_DECODE: DecodeBrunsli returned 0
LERC_DECODE: lerc_getBlobInfo returned Failed
NUMPY_DECODE: not a numpy array
```

The code that is causing this is:

```
 imwrite(filepath[:-4] + '.jpg', imread(filepath)[:,:,:3].copy())
```

Comment: You use some code you don't show to open an image we can't see and would like us to tell you what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that @MarkSetchell.  The code is:

imwrite(filepath[:-4] + '.jpg', imread(filepath)[:,:,:3].copy())

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/62860068/2836621

Comment: `TIFF_DECODE: Sorry, can not handle image`: the libtiff library can't handle the particular TIFF file. Try another library such as [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) to open the file. Anyway, you code makes the assumption that the TIFF file contains a RGB image, which is not always the case.

Comment: @cgohlke the code that I am using for imagecodecs is this:

```
from PIL import Image
from imagecodecs import imread, imwrite

imwrite(filepath[:-4] + '.jpg', imread(filepath)[:,:,:3].copy())
img = Image.open(filepath[:-4] + '.jpg')
img = img.convert('RGB')
imageResize = img.resize((2500, 2500))
imageResize.save(filepath[:-4] + '.jpg')

```
How should it be written so this doesn't happen and still continues to convert TIFFs that have transparencies or not on them?

Comment: Please put code in your original question - it’s hard to read in the comments.

Comment: @cgohlke I ran into another issue when running the above code.  It throws a ValueError that says all data values must be < 4096 for a TIFF file that it is trying to convert.  What is the fix for this?

Comment: @cgohlke can you elaborate on your comment from July 16th?  Where in my code is it making the assumption that the TIFF file contains a RGB image?  Are you saying to use a completely different way to convert these files besides imagecodecs?